# Backup files with dir structure bash script

Tags: linux, bash, find, backup

I'm making a bash script that should backup all files and dir structure to another dir.
I made the following code to do that:

```
find . -type f -exec cp {} $HOME/$bdir \; -o -type d -exec mkdir -p {} $HOME/$bdir \; ;
```

The problem is, is that this only copies the files and not the dir structure.

NOTE: I may not use `cp -r`, `cp -R` or something like it because this code is part of an assignment.

I hope somebody can put me in the right direction. ;)

Joeri

EDIT:

I changed it to:

```
find . -type d -exec mkdir -p $HOME/$bdir/{} \; ;
find . -type f -exec cp {} $HOME/$bdir/{} \; ;
```

And it works! Ty guys ;)

Comment: if your original command had ended with ...  mkdir -p $HOME/$bdir/{}  I think it would have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a job for [rsync](http://man.cx/rsync).

You mention that this is an assignment.  What are your restrictions?  Are you limited to only using `find`?  Does it have to be a single command?

One way to do this is to do it in two `find` calls.  The first call only looks for directories.  When a directory is found, `mkdir` the corresponding directory in the destination hierarchy.  The second `find` call would look for files, and would use a `cp` command like you currently have.

You can also take each filename, transform the path manually, and use that with the `cp` command.  Here's an example of how to generate the destination filename:

```
> find . -type f | sed -e "s|^\./|/new/dir/|"
/new/dir/file1.txt
/new/dir/file2.txt
/new/dir/dir1/file1_1.txt
/new/dir/dir1/file1_2.txt
```

For your purposes, you could write a short bash script that take the source file as input, uses `sed` to generate the destination filename, and then passes those two paths to `cp`.  The `dirname` command will return the directory portion of a filename, so `mkdir -p $(dirname $destination_path)` will ensure that the destination directory exists before you call `cp`.  Armed with a script like that, you can simply have `find` execute the script for every file it finds.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd olddir; tar c . | (cd newdir; tar xp)
```

Comment: came across this while searching for a way to move a directory, its structure, and all its contents, to another directory. Your options works like a charm and is quite compact. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you do your `find` with **"-type d"** and exec a **"mkdir -p"** first, followed by your find that copies the files rather than having it all in one command? It should probably also be **mkdir -p $HOME/$bdir/{}**.

Comment: you could merge them into the same find with two different expressions for what it's worth.

Comment: just noticed that, except he's put the {} in the wrong place in the mkdir. I think the original should have worked.